# How to force PHP script to be resource hungry?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, cpu-usage

I have this **PHP** script created for migrating data. I want it to take as much CPU usage without actually modifying the script.

I run it on the command-line like so:

```
php migration-script.php
```

I tried **nice** to increase its priority level

```
nice --10 php migration-script.php
```

but its still using the same amount of CPU usage.

Using the command line, how to force PHP script to be resource hungry? ex: 75% CPU usage

Comment: I have no answer for this but I'm genuinely curios: why would you want to increase the cpu usage?

Comment: Take a look at all the resouces it is using. If its a migration I would expect that I/O would be its limiting factor and not CPU

Comment: @Andrew the processor is a resource sitting there idle most of the time. I want to utilize it optimally. I want it not to be lazy and do things as fast as it could.

Comment: @RiggsFolly that's right, its reading blobs in the database and generate literal images (jpg), store it to filesystem. Could that be the I/O bottleneck you were talking about?

Comment: You should definitely monitor disk load (and share the results with us).

Comment: As pointed out by @RiggsFolly there's most likely a different limiting factor than the cpu. The cpu will always go as fast as possible, though distributing its processing power over all processes currently using the cpu. Setting the priority simply tells the cpu to distribute more processing power to that process than the others. If there aren't any other processes using the cpu, it won't make any difference. On the code level you could implement multi-threading instead, but you didn't want to change the php code.

Comment: @icecub so, on the execution level, **nice** is the best thing that I could do? And, multi-threading should make the processor even busier?

Comment: Its too early to call it a bottleneck. I was just saying, if its only using 10% CPU then thats all it needs. For all we know the limiting factor could be getting large blobs transfered over a network from DB

Comment: **nice** is only usefull if you have other processes using up the cpu's processing power. Multi-threading means that instead of using just one of your cpu's cores, it can use all of them. If you have 8 cores for example, each core would process 1/8 of your code simultaneously